# How to fix Android Chrome 10px font-size issues?

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome

Using 10px font-size in Chrome on Android causes some spacing issues and miss alignment.

Are there any fix or is it reported as a bug?

First image is a screenshot from Safari on iOS. The second image is from Chrome (v55) on Android 6.0.1.

[image: iOS Safari]

[image: Android Chrome]

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            font-size: 16px;
        }
        span {
            background: red;
            font-size: 10px;
        }
        span.em {
            font-size: 0.625em;
        }
        span.small {
            font-size: 8px;
        }
        span.big {
            font-size: 12px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <span class="small">Test</span>
    <span>Test</span>
    <span class="em">Test</span>
    <span class="big">Test</span>
</body>
</html>
```